# Forms - Phone Number Validation

Tags: html, css, validation, phone-number

I am attempting to create a function that will allow a phone number between 9-11 digits long (Currently the function is allowing 11 digits).

When I write the function for the phone number checker and place it at the bottom of my JavaScript, my email checker function no longer works properly. 
I need to find a solution that will allow both the email and phone number functions to work.

If anyone has a solution your input would be great.

[image]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M6N24/526/)

HTML:

```
<form class="container" action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
  <label>First Name
    <input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label>Last Name
    <input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label>Email
    <input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label>Phone
    <input id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label>City
    <input id="city" name="city" maxlength="40" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label>State/Province
    <input id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label id="co">Company
    <input id="company" name="company" type="text" onkeyup="test()"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label>Comments
    <textarea id="comments"name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" onkeyup="test()"></textarea>
    <input id="sub" type="submit" disabled="disabled" />
  </label>

  <div>                
      <select  hidden="true" id="00N6A000008yXMN" name="00N6A000008yXMN" title="Product Interest">
      <option value="">--None--</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="Visiant">Visiant</option>
      <option  value="Tessellate">Tessellate</option>
  </select><br>

  <select  hidden="true" id="lead_source" name="lead_source">
      <option value="">--None--</option>
      <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
  <option value="Trade Show">Trade Show</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="Website">Website</option>
  <option value="Direct Marketing">Direct Marketing</option>
  <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select><br>
  </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f78e2a;
  text-align: center;
} 

form {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f78e2a;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Lato;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-title {
    font-size: 38px;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: "Lato";
    letter-spacing: 70px;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

textarea:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#co {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

label:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

select,
label {
  height: 50px;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 2% 1%;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Lato";
}

#sub {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;

}

button {
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: #B9B9B9;
  color: #959595;
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-left: 1%;
  display: block;
}


button:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #f78e2a;
}

@media (max-width: 426px) {
  label {
    width: 98%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 426px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-self: flex-start;
  }
}

label {
  position: relative;
}

.fa {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, -5%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s, color .5s;
}


[data-valid] + .fa {
  opacity: 1;
  color: green;
}

[data-valid="valid"] + .fa {
  color: green;
}

[data-valid="error"] + .fa {
  color: red;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
  return re.test(email);
}

$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#email')) {
      if (validateEmail($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
        console.log("this works")
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      console.log("this works")
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');
    console.log("this works")
  }
});


test = function() {
  if ($("#first_name").val() && $("#last_name").val() && $("#email").val() && $("#phone").val() && $("#city").val() && $("#state").val() && $("#company").val()) {
    $("#sub").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}

function phoneNumber(phone)  {  
  var phoneno = /^\d{11}$/;  
  return phoneno.test(phone);
}

$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#phone')) {
      if (phoneNumber($(this).val())) {
        $(this).attr('data-valid','valid');
      } else {
        $(this).attr('data-valid','error');
        console.log("this works")
      }
    } else {
      $(this).attr('data-valid','valid');
        console.log("this works")
    }
  } else {
    $(this).removeAttr('data-valid');
    console.log("this works")
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started from your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45081559/display-correct-fa-fa-icons-inside-phone-and-email-input-boxes)... About your phone length validation.

```
var phoneno = /^\d{9}|\d{10}|\d{11}$/;
```

The above will return true if it finds a sequence of 9, 10 or 11 digits...
But also for 12, 13, up to n digits.

Here is how you should limit from 9 to 11 digits, using regex:

```
var phoneno = /^\d{9,11}$/;
```

A short note about `<input type="tel">`, it isn't browser compatible yet,  [as shown here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/%3Cinput_type=_tel_%3E).

Comment: Thank you for that!  Now I am trying to make the form disappear  on submit and for a "thank you" box to show up.  I'll be posting it in a new question soon.  Here is my fiddle for it: http://jsfiddle.net/vvffpjxb/7/

Comment: You will need to use ajax for it.

Answer (score 0):

You're binding twice to all inputs with type text. Just bind once and check both inputs in that one callback:

(And for the love of Pete stop recreating your $(this) object every time)

```
$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $this = $(this); 
  var $label = $this.closest('label');
  if ($this.val().trim() != '') {
    if ($this.is('#email')) {
      if (validateEmail($this.val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
        console.log("this works")
      }
    } else if ($this.is('#phone')) {
      if (phoneNumber($this.val())) {
        $this.attr('data-valid','valid');
      } else {
        $this.attr('data-valid','error');
        console.log("this works")
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
      console.log("this works")
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');
    console.log("this works")
  }
});
```

Comment: This solution did not work for me as the fa fa icons would no longer display.  I did however solve the problem by changing the type input for phone to 'tel' Here is a fiddle for it: http://127.0.0.1:8080/#contact